# Displaying pattern in haystack

Tags: php, regex, string, variables

Is there a means to return the pattern found from within an input variable, with the possible addition of highlighting the pattern within the variable? (e.g. for Regex, returning the input variable with the pattern found)

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: There certainly is a means. You might just add html markup for example to make it e.g. bold. Please explain how and where this is a coding problem for you. Right now that question is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your question is a bit unclear, it sounds like you would like to merely highlight or mark in some form or fashion a substring (or perhaps a pattern) of a larger string. There are many ways to go about this, depending especially on the substring/pattern you'd like to search, but here's a simple example:

```
$input = "There is a pattern in this string. Mark the pattern.";

// There is a <em>pattern</em> in this string. Mark the <em>pattern</em>
echo preg_replace( "/(pattern)/", "<em>$1</em>", $input );
```

Of course this merely replaces the pattern with a modified version, returning the full string. Other functions, like `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` can return an array of the matched patterns. Again, it all depends on what your precise needs are.

Answer (score -1):

Try using preg_match

```
preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: As a note, you were likely downvoted because these kind of answers are not really good.  Look above for some better examples of how to answer.